# Problem with a Do Carmo problem

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to solve some Do Carmo problems from his book *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces*. In section 1-3 prob.5.c., we have the curve: $\alpha:(-1,\infty)\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ given by: $$\alpha(t)=(\frac{3at}{1+t^3},\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3})$$
And they ask: *take the curve with the opposite orientation. Now, as* $t\to-1$, *the curve and its tagent approach the line* $x+y+a=0$.

I wasn't really sure of what was supose to hapen, but I took the derivative of $\alpha$:
$$\alpha'(-t)=(\frac{3a(1-t^2+3t^3)}{(1+t^3)^2},\frac{-3at(2-2t^3-3t^4)}{(1+t^3)^2})$$
And then I looked for the limit if  $\alpha,\alpha'$ when $t\to -1$ to see what happened, but I got that they both tend to constants as spected since both are continuous, so what happened? What am I supose to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to see that the vector with the constant components you get is parallel to the limit line. Moreover you are supposed to show that the curve itself, as $t\rightarrow -1$, approaches that line.